# m2e eclipse requesting for a login / password when downloading maven index updates

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e

I just finished installing Eclipse Luna 4.4 and M2E Eclipse plugin (v1.5.0) ; configured the settings file located at the `$M2_HOME/conf/settings.xml`.

Then I configured the M2E plugin to tell him to point to this configuration file I've just made.

However, when Eclipse is updating the Maven index, it asks me for a username / password that I've indicated in the settings.xml file...

Note that I am behind a proxy configured in native mode (in eclipse) which works fine.

My question: why is eclipse opening a dialog box asking me for this login/pwd when I have specified the logins information needed?

When I look in the maven console view in eclipse, he download my artifacts well... Strange.

In advance, thank you,

**Edit: It appears that this is a bug --->** https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=440273

Hope this would help ! Solved.

JuriexFF

Comment: I had the same problem. Thanks for pointing at the known bug. Updating m2e to 1.6.0-SNAPSHOT resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the final solution I used was to update m2e to 1.6.0-SNAPSHOT. The versions before this one contains this bug.

I didn't checked on their repositories but I am quite certain that there is a 1.6.0 release out now.

Hope it helps !